# Hadoop LongSumReducer

Tags: hadoop

I'm using hadoop "2.0.0-cdh4.1.1" and I try to use `LongSumReducer` for my wordCount program.

```
job.setReducerClass((new LongSumReducer<Text>()).getClass());
```

However there's a compilation error:

```
setReducerClass(java.lang.Class<? extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer>) in
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class<capture#402 of
extends org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.LongSumReducer>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it implementing the correct interface or extending the correct class for the reducer implementation. The exception says a package difference in the implementation method required vs the usage (new vs old hadoop api)

Comment: I try to use the provided LongSumReducer class in hadoop library instead of implementing or extending LongSumReducer.

Comment: I think you have to use the new api, see the difference between the package name mapred and mapreduce. The exception says it is a different package.

Comment: Yes, all the classes except LongSumReduce are in mapreducer package. LongSumReducer is in mapred package. Does this mean that if there's no LongSumReduce in mapreducer package and I'm not able to use it. I don't quite follow. Thank you.

Comment: I got it. I found the LongSumReduce class in mapreducer package. It takes me a whole day. Thank you so much.